# How can I use <input type=datetime > and iOS Safari with Django?

Tags: html, django-forms, mobile-safari, datetimepicker

I really like the convenience of the special keyboard for  in Safari iOS.

However, it seems to output datetimes in the format 'Feb 10, 2013, 9:07'.

Django forms won't parse this format. As in the django documentation, django doesn't parse %b or %B, abbreviated or full month names.

Any easy workaround to get django forms to parse 'Feb 10, 2013, 9:07'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format actually is `2013-02-10T09:07:00Z`, it just renders as `Feb 10, 2013, 9:07` (or according to your locale settings). As the format is a standard datetime format, I think Django should be able to handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Django doesn't support the format used by the HTML5 datetime or datetime-local inputs, so you'll need to add it manually using a custom format module, for example:

(replace 'mysite' in the examples with your project's name)

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'mysite.formats'
```

in your settings.py

and

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
    '%Y-%m-%d',
    '%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S',
    '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',
    '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
    '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M',
    '%Y/%m/%d',
)
```

in `mysite/formats/en/formats.py`

Make sure to also create

```
mysite/formats/__init__.py
mysite/formats/en/__init__.py
```

and copy the `en` directory for any other locales you use.